# Numbering Items in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

So I have an items.py with the following:

```
class ScrapyItem(scrapy.Item):
    source = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
```

and the json output is:

```
[{"source": "Some source", "link":"www.somelink.com"},
 {"source": "Some source again", "link":"www.somelink.org"}]
```

is there a way change the output to:

```
[{"source1": "Some source", "link1":"www.somelink.com"},
 {"source2": "Some source again", "link2":"www.somelink.org"}]
```

From the docs, I saw you can manipulate the item values, can you do the same to the items themselves?

**EDIT**

Here's the new code I'm using for the output with an article_id item_field

```
article_id = [1]
def parse_common(self, response):
    feed = feedparser.parse(response.body)
    for entry_n, entry in enumerate(feed.entries, start=article_id[-1]):
        try:
            item = NewsbyteItem()
            item['source'] = response.url
            item['title'] = lxml.html.fromstring(entry.title).text
            item['link'] = entry.link
            item['description'] = entry.description
            item['article_id'] = '%d' % entry_n
            article_id.append(entry_n)
            request = Request(
                entry.link,
                callback=getattr(self, response.meta['method']),
                dont_filter=response.meta.get('dont_filter', False)
            )

            request.meta['item'] = item
            request.meta['entry'] = entry

            yield request
        except Exception as e:
            print '%s: %s' % (type(e), e)
            print entry
```

The problem is the entry_n restarts whenever it changes to another url. That's why the list was used.

Comment: to clarify, you want all links be numbered in some sequence - of what? sequence of retrieval? sequence of writing to output? note that scrapy is multi-threaded and as such there is no native total order of items retrieved. Depending on your actual requirements there are probably several possible solutions.

Comment: why not just save links in a list?

Comment: I want a unique identifier for each one.After thinking about it, I decided to create a new item field called id and then used the enumerate function in a for loop. At first, whenever it changed source (an RSS feed) the id restarted at "1". so the output had two dicts with an id of "1". I then used a list variable first containing [1] then appended the latest number. The code was as  follows: for entry_n, entry in enumerate(foo, start=list[-1]). I got the result I wanted. But is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @hoolioo this looks like your list grows unbounded (might eventually run out of memory). setting concerns for concurrent spider instances aside, why not use a simple counter, instead of a list?

Comment: @miraculixx I edited the post so you can see why I'm having difficulty with a simple counter. I'm still a novice programmer but I'm having trouble going about this with a counter.

Comment: @miraculixx  The list method in the code works but yeah the unbound list will be a problem. I've tried to make a counter but it repeats whenever the spider goes to a new url. The output with have multipe article_ids with "1" depending on how many urls I have.

Comment: @hooliooo was my answer the solution to your question? Was it useful? Do you need something more?

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire it gave me the idea of the article_id field. I just need to figure that part out

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire I was in a hurry when I replied. I just need the article_id to be the unique item identifier without using a list as in my current code then I'll have my answer. Thank you for that input. It put me in the right direction

Comment: All right then @hooliooo. Tag my answer as a solution for next people with the same trouble please. :)

Comment: @hooliooo the problem with this approach (list or counter) is that everytime scrapy loads or reloads your module, the counter is reset to `[1]`. can you elaborate the scenario that you are trying to achieve (i.e. why do you need an id field in the first place, what do you want to use this field for? could a UUID help instead of a counter? etc.).

Comment: @miraculixx Actually that isn't a problem with the list approach the "start" argument in the enumerate function uses the last element in the list which is appended every time in the for loop. The counter approach results in duplicate ids. The purpose of the identifier is if an item has some data missing or includes data that isn't needed, I can find that dictionary right away and refactor the code accordingly. (the output is a json file) –

Comment: @hooliooo with that purpose in mind, I'd suggest to generate UUIDs. Same effect, less hassle.

Comment: @miraculixx Alright thanks for the help! I'm using uuid4()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the discussion

> The purpose of the identifier is if an item has some data missing or includes data that isn't needed, I can find that dictionary right away and refactor the code accordingly.

With that purpose in mind, I'd suggest to generate UUIDs. Same effect, less hassle:

```
# item definition
class ScrapyItem(scrapy.Item):
    source = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    uuid = scrapy.Field()
# processing
def parse_common(self, response):
    ...
    item['uuid'] = uuid.uuid4()
    ...
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't recommend you to identify different items changing the key of your item's values. You can do instead a dictionary with naming the responses doing something like:

```
output = [{"source": "Some source", "link":"www.somelink.com"}, {"source": "Some source again", "link":"www.somelink.org"}]
output_dict = {}
for counter, item in enumerate(output):
    output_dict['item' + str(counter + 1)] = item
print output_dict
```